# How to automate Grails build?

Tags: grails, build-automation

What tools shall be used to automate Grails build? Ant? Shell? Would be good to read some official documentation about it.

Comment: did you see this? http://urblog.giolist.com/2008/01/building-grails-applications-with.html

Comment: thanks for the link, it simply suggests to do `grails upgrade; grails test; grails war`, which is not bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out-of-the-box Grails provides a build system that can be used to compile, run tests, create a .war, deploy to tomcat, etc.

This build system is implemented using GAnt, which is a Groovy DSL over Ant. You can extend/customise the build system by writing your own GAnt scripts. The scripts provided by Grails provide well defined hooks that you can use to customise the build lifecycle.

What exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to configure my CI server to build a WAR file and deploy it to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: I don't know what protocols Amazon support for remote deployment, but assuming it's something fairly mainstream like SCP or HTTPS, then it should be fairly simple to write a GAnt script that performs the deployent.

Answer (score 2):

The tool we use to automate builds at work is Hudson.

http://hudson-ci.org/

We use it for all our software, including a Grails project.  I don't know the specifics, since I'm not in charge of the build system.

Comment: Hudson is a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool, not a [build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool. They are two different things...

Comment: Our Hudson jobs take care of the five bullet points mentioned under the build automation article you link.

Answer (score 1):

Im using [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) as a build and dependency management tool. [Here](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin) you can find a plugin for building Grails projects. At the end, I use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) as continuous integration server.